# Client implementation within QML application

Tags: qt, client, qml

I'm developping an application using `QML` files which are regularly updated by data coming from a server.

I have a custom TCPClient class that I need to implement in order to listen to the server's answers.

Here's what it would look like:

```
tcp_client.loop()
   getDataFromServer()
   updateCurrentQMLPage(data)
```

Whereas the `QML` pages switch between themselves automatically.

I was thinking about settting my class as a context priority:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("tcp_client", TCPClient::get()); // static pointer
```

Being a beginner in QML applications, I was wondering if this would make my class dependent from the `QML` code and if the algorithm presented above would work.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand what you're trying to do, but this could be the case of registering a QObject-derived C++ class in qml to implement the use of the TCP socket and declaring an object (or maybe multiple depending on your case) of said class in qml. This way you could have properties, functions and signals/slots declared in C++ available in qml. [This page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) has some links that could help, since C++/qml interaction can be done in multiple ways.

I'm using a similar approach right now, but instead of a TCP socket my backend listens to a named pipe for messages containing protobuf-formatted data. I have a class in C++ that aggregates a QLocalSocket (pipe) and every time new data is available, the message is parsed and passed to qml as an argument in a signal. (the qml object even has a slot automatically generated for said signal).

Comment: I am also reading a container with protobuf-formatted data. You understood what I wanted to achieve. It seems like my approach is a good one, according to this [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html).